# Failed to extract videos through json from youtube

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, youtube, xmlhttprequest

Sometimes I get this error when extracting youtube videos by json, here's an example:

XMLHttpRequest can not load https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/IcarusTouma?&alt=json. Origin http://localhost is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

I tried with jsonp, but youtube does not accept jsonp.

So extract videos from youtube.

```
$. getJSON ('https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/' + id_video + '? & alt = json', function (data) {
if (typeof data! == "undefined" && data)
{
     var title = data ['entry'] ['title'] ['$ t'];
     var thumb = data ['entry'] ['media $ group'] ['media $ thumbnail'] [0] ['url'];
     var title = data ['entry'] ['author'] [0] ['name'] ['$ t'];
     $. getJSON ('https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/' + author + '? & alt = json', function (data) {

     author_thumbnail var = data ['entry'] ['media $ thumbnail'] ['url'];
     $ ('.items').append(html_carousel (thumb, title, author_thumbnail, author, 5,' youtube ', id_video, author'));

     });
}
});
```

Comment: try adding "&callback=?" in your url.

Comment: if the remote server doesn't reply in JSONP, then you can't get data from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having just checked the YouTube Data API reference documentation, for both JSON and the newer JSON-C formats, they both accept JSON-P, allowing you to specify the callback by the `callback` GET string parameter. This link will demonstrate that this is true:

https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=baseball&v=2&alt=jsonc&callback=functionName

The long JSON object return is wrapped in the function call to `functionName`, in this case. The next URL is the same call, but in the older (and somewhat deprecated) JSON format:

https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=baseball&v=2&alt=json&callback=functionName

The data is a bit different, but same result set, wrapped in another call to `functionName`. Now, these calls were queries to get the videos that matched the search param ("baseball"). But I'm sure perusing their reference documents (for the [JSON-C](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_jsonc) and [JSON](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_json) formats) will yield what you need to make this work properly, as a JSONP call, specifying the callback in the query string.

Answer (score 0):

Use `dataType: 'jsonp'` in the ajax call.

See: http://jsfiddle.net/D4tEk/

Comment: Looks like this API is dead, it returns HTTP 410 GONE