# youtube api feed

Tags: youtube

I am trying to load a jsonc feed, but I get an error:

"Jsonc is not enabled for this feed"

```
var url ='http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/GoProCamera?v=2&alt=jsonc';
$.ajax({
url: url,
dataType: 'jsonp',
success: function(response){
},
error:function(er){
console.log("Error: " , er);
},
});
```

Is there a way to check is jsonc is enabled?

Comment: try adding "&callback=?" in your url. http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/GoProCamera?v=2&alt=jsonc&callback=functionName

Comment: and refer this question too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9552168/failed-to-extract-videos-through-json-from-youtube

Comment: But what i am getting with the parameter? This is just a function that will get called in a case of success? Is that correct?

Comment: I did not thoroughly go through the documentation it self, but as it seems to me if you want to make JSONP call you need to specify the callback function as in that will be a function of your own. success: function